# Getting error while updating the chart.js version 3.9.1 to 4.3.0 in vue2 project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js, vue-chartjs

Currently, I'm using chart.js 3.9.1.I want to upgrade the version 4.3.0 for new features.
Getting below error while updating 4.3.0 then run the vue2 project.
[image]

### package.json :

"chart.js": "^3.9.1",

```
./node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js 567:17
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (567:17)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     };
| class DatasetController {
>  static defaults = {};
|  static datasetElementType = null;
|  static dataElementType = null;
```

Comment: Have a look to the comment in chartjs repo, about the same issue: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/11375#issuecomment-1620267647